# WebView fails to load webpage

Tags: android, webview

I have a `WebView` trying to load a WebPage like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
    wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings ws=wv.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://pro39.blutechnologies.com/crimes.aspx");
}
```

I have added the internet permission to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

However the WebView is blank,it neither throws an error nor loads the web-page.How do I load webpages like this,I have only tried loading local `html` files before and I would like to know if I have to do something different.

Comment: are you able to view that url on your browser too ? I know url is working fine.

Comment: yes,I can view the url in the browser

Comment: ok, are you trying this code in emulator or in real device ?

Comment: Im loading this on a real device

Comment: I create new project and ran your code, it is working fine in my emulator.

Comment: @user2309862, can you try my below code and check. Let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this way:

```
 mWebView.loadUrl("http://pro39.blutechnologies.com/crimes.aspx");  
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

  private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
 }
```

Use this code `.shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` not use compulsary.use this code and please reply me this code work or not

Comment: It works,was the page redirecting somewhere else...or is this nessecary whenever I use a url,will accept answer as soon as I can.

Comment: just return false; from shouldOverrideUrlLoading. Calling view.loadUrl will result in problems if the page has an iframe with a custom scheme.

Comment: @marcin.kosiba i dont know much more about iframe. but it's working in my case.

Comment: yes, whether you hit the problem or not depends on the HTML you're trying to load. It will also work if you just return false; try it out ;)

Comment: @marcin.kosiba let me check. wait

Comment: Also, just to prove my point - load http://jsbin.com/gupug/1/quiet using your current shouldOverrideUrlLoading implementation.

Comment: @marcin.kosiba you are absolutely right.it's working with return false value. it's strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebview ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

        mWebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("http://pro39.blutechnologies.com/crimes.aspx");
        setContentView(mWebview );
    }
}
```