# Failed loading a form action in a webview app

Tags: android, webview

I am developing a `WebView` app. so then the app loads a web that has a form on it. when I click the button to processed, the app failed to load as you can see in the picture

[image]

I've been trying following the code from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7528833/10778924 and also from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7528833/10778924 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21899709/10778924

here's my code that I apply

```
webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }else {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
```

and

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

but it still not works for me. the app still failed to load when I click a button to processed my form.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ok its working fine so I am giving you a code to run your url.

   webView.loadUrl("https://sipenting.000webhostapp.com/user/testingtk");

   openWebView();



    add above line in oncreate methode and below code out side of onCreate methode. It will 
      working fine. and for progressbar you can simply remove it or just define a progress 
      bar in your xml code.


    public void openWebView () {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }
        });
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
//                Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle(title);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: i already try your code, but the problem still the same. actually, my web that been loaded on my app is codeigniter (php) page. so, is that possible the problem is the max_execution_time? because the default is 30 second. and my app failed loading after 90 seconds

Comment: Sorry I don't about but you can try with Max time number because you have to give a response to user like url not interact than just open other page...

Answer (score 0):

here's my code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        Uri[] results = null;
        //checking if response is positive
        if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                if(null == mUMA){
                    return;
                }
                if(intent == null || intent.getData() == null){
                    if(mCM != null){
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                    }
                }else{
                    String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                    if(dataString != null){
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    } else {
                        if(multiple_files) {
                            if (intent.getClipData() != null) {
                                final int numSelectedFiles = intent.getClipData().getItemCount();
                                results = new Uri[numSelectedFiles];
                                for (int i = 0; i < numSelectedFiles; i++) {
                                    results[i] = intent.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUMA = null;
    }else{
        if(requestCode == FCR){
            if(null == mUM) return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUM = null;
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
@SuppressWarnings({"findViewById", "RedundantCast"})
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //tombol back
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //title action bar
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Deteksi TBS Tanpa Kotak");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mProgressBar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    mProgressBar.setMax(100);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
    }

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ifView);
    assert webView != null;
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }else {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    webView.loadUrl("https://sipenting.000webhostapp.com/user/testingtk"); //add your test web/page address here
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        /*
         * openFileChooser is not a public Android API and has never been part of the SDK.
         */
        //handling input[type="file"] requests for android API 16+
        @SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUM = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            if (multiple_files && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            }
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
        }

        //handling input[type="file"] requests for android API 21+
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

            //checking for storage permission to write images for upload
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, perms, FCR);

                //checking for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
            } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, FCR);

                //checking for CAMERA permissions
            } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, FCR);
            }
            if (mUMA != null) {
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUMA = filePathCallback;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                }
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
            if (multiple_files) {
                contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            }
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "File Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            mProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
        }
    });
}

//callback reporting if error occurs
public class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

//creating new image file here
private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
}

//back/down key handling
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode){
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(webView.canGoBack()){
                    webView.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}